# How to automatically display images with Android's PagerAdapter class?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

Since the gallery widget for android is deprecated, I found another approach to implement the photo gallery.

Class **ImageAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private int curPlayImg= 0; 
private ImageView imageView;
private Handler advPageHandler = new Handler();

public Integer[] mThumbIds={
        R.drawable.adv_pic1,
        R.drawable.adv_pic2,
        R.drawable.adv_pic3 ,
        R.drawable.adv_pic4,
        R.drawable.adv_pic5 
};

public ImageAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context= context;
}

/**
 * return the image number.
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {

    return view==((ImageView)obj);  
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    imageView.setImageResource( mThumbIds[ position ] );                        
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}
```

Class FullscreenActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    ViewPager viewPager= (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    ImageAdapter adapter= new ImageAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It works well, but I want the images in the ImageAdapter to display one by one automatically.
Thus I create a **thread** to handle it.

I add a method in the 
Class **ImageAdapter.java**

```
public void displayAdv()
{
    Timer timer= new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
        advPageHandler.post(
         new Runnable(){
          public void run()
              {
           imageView.setImageResource( mThumbIds[ curPlayImg] );
            curPlayImg++;
                curPlayImg= curPlayImg % getCount();                    
                            }
                 });
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

and call the method:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity{

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    ViewPager viewPager= (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    ImageAdapter adapter= new ImageAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.displayAdv();
}
```

But I got an error message:

Error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10295): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at                com.example.testview3.ImageAdapter$1$1.run(ImageAdapter.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:850)
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
E/AndroidRuntime(10295):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have create an object **adapter** and it should already **instantiateItem** so I am confused

1. Why this error happen?
2. How to fix it?
3. Any better alternative code?

Answer (score 0):

I feel your approach is right. Use a View Pager as the container for the Pager Adapter. Next, you can use the folowing API of ViewPager:

```
public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll)
```

This will make a transition to the specified page. You can create some sort of a timer or whatever suites your need to iterate over pages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will appreciate at it if you can provide some examples.